# Import Thunderbird's Address Book into Yosemite's Mail app

Tags: thunderbird, apple-mail, address-book

I need to Import Thunderbird's Address Book into Yosemite's Mail app. I tried from Thunderbird (last OS X version) to export all addresses to different formats (CSV, LDIF, etc) but none of them can be imported into Contacts app. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple KB - [Contacts: Export and import your contacts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11586)

> **Import one or more contacts (from a file other than a vCard)**
>
> You can import contact information that you saved or exported from other apps. The files can be in LDAP Interchange Format (LDIF) or text format (tab-delimited or comma-separated value (CSV)).
>
> 1. If you’re importing a tab-delimited or CSV file, verify it using a text editor such as TextEdit.
>
>    - Remove any line breaks within a contact’s information. Line breaks can cause the import to fail.
>    - Make sure that fields in a tab-delimited file are separated by a tab, instead of by another character. Don’t include spaces before or after tabs.
>    - Make sure that fields in a CSV file are separated by a comma, instead of by another character. Don’t include spaces before or after commas.
>    - Make sure all addresses have the same number of fields. Add empty fields as needed.
> 2. In Contacts, choose File > Import, select the file, change the encoding if necessary, and then click Open.
> 3. If you’re importing a text file, review the field labels. You can change field labels, or ignore or not import fields.
>
>    - If the first card contains headers, make sure the headers are correctly labeled or marked “Do not import.” Any changes you make to this card are made in all of the cards in the file. To not import the headers card, select the “Ignore first card” checkbox.
>    - To change a label, click the arrows next to the label and choose a new label. If you don’t want to import a field, choose “Do not import.”
>
> If a contact has custom fields, the information in the fields isn’t imported.
>
> When you import contacts into an Exchange account, information that isn’t supported in Contacts is added to the Notes field.

Comment: is it there some script or tool that allows to easily do this????

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.